# Ktor Error: Unable to initialize main class Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I have a strange problem with Ktor.

Everything runs smoothly when I setup the project. Also, in a few couple of days, everything runs as expected. I can run the app and see it running in localhost.

But, when I get back to the project after a month, with nothing changed, I get a strange error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class {my_package_name}.ApplicationKt
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineScope
```

This is not just for one project.

My Application.kt:
[image]

Anyone with a similar issue? Searching the Internet doesn't return anything, so I'm posting this question.

Comment: Forgot to mention. Debug start is working just fine. Without it, I would be totally blocked.

Comment: This is probably the problem with the Gradle cache. Can you try deleting the `~/.m2` and `~/.gradle` directories?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Have no ~/.m2. Deleted ~/.gradle, restarted the IntelliJ IDEA and still the same problem persists.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem by running your application via the command line (without IDEA)?

Comment: Do you have `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm")` in your build.gradle.kts file?

Comment: @k314159 Nop. Added it, synced the gradle. Started the app. And now it works. Have no idea why. It was working just fine a month ago without it...

Comment: @AlekseiTirman How to run the app via console? 

Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: You can execute the `./gradlew run` command if the Gradle `Application` plugin is applied.